# Storage folder is not accessible on live server in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am working on a Laravel project, I am uploading images via Admin Panel which are storing in Storage directory. When I try to access the images then it works fine on localhost. i.e.

The image is accessible by following URL on localhost:

```
http://localhost:8000/storage/default3.png
```

But when I try to access the same image on live server:

```
http://13.57.71.20/serio/storage/default3.png
```

then it doesn't work.

**NOTE:** serio is the folder where project is uploaded on server.

But it does work if I try the following way:

```
http://13.57.71.20/serio/storage/app/public/default3.png
```

I also tried to re-link the Storage directory by running following command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

but nothing helped.

Comment: Read this maybe it could help. https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e

Comment: Try `chmod -R o+w project/storage`

Comment: @HirenGohel Tried, nothing happened

Comment: Try to add this in the appServiceProvider `App::make('files')->link(storage_path('app/public'), public_path('storage'));` and check again !!

Comment: it throw an error: "symlink(): File exists"

Comment: Hi Amrinder. I've edited a number of your posts, to fix the case errors, please-help-me chat and home-made title tags. Volunteer editors do appreciate it when question authors examine the edits made to their posts, so they can learn about the quality and succinctness we like here. Would you respond to me please, to assure me that you will take care of these items in the future?

Comment: Downvoted (see above).

Answer (score 0):

Change following line in .env file

```
APP_URL=http://13.57.71.20/serio
```

Comment: Run `php artisan config:clear` then `php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my view, it seems is with production url. You running it on production on url:

```
http://13.57.71.20/serio/
```

Seems to me that the directory alias `serio` is not properly configured for Apache/Nginx. Try running the app under `http://13.57.71.20/` or you need to add an alias to the default host configuration for `serio` which you should map to your laravel app `public` folder.